# Intellij Nuxt error: TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

Tags: typescript, vue.js, intellij-idea, nuxt.js

I'm trying Nuxt 3 for the first time. I've created a basic app following the Getting Started instructions for the Content module https://content.nuxtjs.org/get-started.

In Intellij, the modules declaration in nuxt.config.ts gives the error:

TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

[image]

Intellij: 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 202

Typescript Config:

NodeInterpreter: 18.7.0

Typescript: Bundled 4.8.4

[image]

Any ideas please?

Comment: Looks like a problem with tsc@4.8.4; I was able get rid of the issue by installing typescript@4.9.4: `npm i typescript@4.9.4 --save-dev` and choosing it instead of `4.8.4` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**

Comment: @lena - thanks, that works! Do you want to add that as answer so I mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a problem with `tsc@4.8.4`; I was able get rid of the issue by installing typescript@4.9.4: `npm i typescript@4.9.4 --save-dev` and choosing it instead of `4.8.4` in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**